# Strcpy and strtok don't work

Tags: c++

I need to print the components of a given char(in this case the numbers which are separated pe whitespece) and I don't understand why this doesn't work(doesn't compile): (or here http://ideone.com/JSrqg5).

The errors are:

```
error C4996: 'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.  c:\users\ellly\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication15446\consoleapplication15446\source.cpp 18  1   ConsoleApplication15446
error C2664: 'char *strcpy(char *,const char *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'char *'    c:\users\ellly\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication15446\consoleapplication15446\source.cpp 21  1   ConsoleApplication15446
```

And the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
char s[20000], *p, a[5000], separator[] = " ";
int k = 0, i;
void separare();
void afisare();
int main()
{
    cout << "Sirul de nr:"; cin.get(s, 100, '\n');
    separare();
    afisare();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void separare()
{
    p = strtok(s, separator);
    while (p)
    {
        strcpy(a[k], p);
        k++;
        p = strtok(NULL, separator);
    }
}
void afisare()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: I think you must include the cstring library: #include <cstring>

Comment: After modifying it just points again to strcpy and strtok .

Comment: What is this "doesn't work" of which you speak?

Comment: @Poldie he means it does not compile, saying strtok and strcpy are not defined. Daniq: does not work is a bad description, it either does not compile then you should provide error, or does not produce expected output, then you should post expected one and what it gives instead.

Comment: http://i58.tinypic.com/k3stjr.png

Comment: Next problem: using external image hosting sites.  They'll go away eventually, leaving this question of less use to future visitors.  Please take the effort to update the question so that it contains all information required to help.

Comment: As the message says: `a[k]` is a `char`, not a `char*`. You can't `strcpy` an entire string into a single character.

Comment: molbdnilo: And how to eliminate the error?

Comment: @Daniq, It depends on what you want to copy, is it the string `a`? is it the string `a` without the `k` first characters? To eliminate the error, you just need to give a variable of type `char*` to `strtok`, but this variable depends on what you actually want to do. Also, **read** the errors, they tell you everything. If you don't understand them, explain what part is confusing you.

Comment: I receive the string "s" which has as components, numbers. The numbers(as strings for now) I want to copy in the vector "a". "k" just counts the components and is used to place them in the vector "a".

Comment: "a" is not a vector; it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok, if you are running on linux though, you must check that the file /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build points to a valid location of your header files (usually in /usr/src/linux-headers-XXXX).
A lot of times after installing new kernel and headers, this link gets broken, and then your programs cannot link to the libraries, and for that reason it won't compile.
Hope it helps.

By the way you cannot use a[k] for strcpy, as this is dereferencing a single char, while the input must be char*. You should use pointer notation instead, i.e (a+k) would work in this case.